# Amazon Linux: Can't log background task output?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, redirection, background-process, amazon-linux

We recently moved to AWS EC2 instances w/ the Amazon Linux distro.

On our old servers (RH Enterprise), we've been able to run a command in the background (`&`) and also redirect the output to a log file, such as the below:

`php /path/to/script > log.txt &`

However, this no longer works on AWS. *log.txt* is created, but is empty.

If I leave off the & so the task runs in the foreground (`php /path/to/script > log.txt`), it works and log.txt contains data.

What am I doing wrong here and/or what can I do to get the output of my scripts logged again?

Thanks in advance.

---

Here's a code sample of what is happening:

```
[ec2-user@ip /]$ cat logtest.php
<?php echo "It's big, it's heavy, it's wood!\n"; ?>
[ec2-user@ip /]$ php logtest.php > log.txt
[ec2-user@ip /]$ cat log.txt
It's big, it's heavy, it's wood!
[ec2-user@ip /]$ rm log.txt
[ec2-user@ip /]$ php logtest.php > log.txt &
[3] 6649
[ec2-user@ip /]$ <I waited 5 seconds and pressed enter here>
[3]+  Stopped                 php logtest.php > log.txt
[ec2-user@ip /]$ cat log.txt
[ec2-user@ip /]$ ll log.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 0 Jan  3 00:30 log.txt
[ec2-user@ip /]$
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure it's related to your /etc/php.ini config or the way the php package is compiled for Amazon Linux. I tried on MacOS and it works fine too. Can you compare the one you have locally to the one you have in AWS.

Try the following on both machines. Create a script called logtest.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "It's big, it's heavy, it's wood!\n"
```

then run:

```
chmod 777 logtest.sh
./logtest.sh > log.txt &
```

If it works on both machines then it's definitely a php configuration issue.

Comment: You can also try running `php -i` on both machines and compare the output and see what's different on the configs.

Comment: This worked as well as Ronald's `echo`, so I guess it's a PHP configuration error. Now to find out what it could be...

Comment: After more digging, it turns out the culprit is the `readline` extension, which was turned on in the copy of PHP that YUM supplies. Doh! http://php.net/manual/en/book.readline.php#107349 Anyone know how I can disable the extension without recompiling? It isn't in php.ini because it was compiled in...

Comment: Upvote for the Ren & Stimpy reference

Answer (score 0):

Try running it with `nohup`

```
nohup php /path/to/script > log.txt &
```

Comment: When I add nohup to my command, it just hangs there instead of automatically sending it to the background like & should do? Even after the process finished I was sitting there waiting on nohup until I hit CTRL+C...

Comment: What is your php script doing ?

Comment: It echos "Hi\n" to the screen and quits. I'll update my question with a code sample.

Comment: If I do `nohup php /path/to/script > log.txt` (no &) and then press CTRL+Z to suspend the job and `bg` to resume it, THAT works... but it's kind of a pain...

Answer (score 0):

Strange...  it works for me, en amazon, but Debian.

```
root@domU-12-31-39-0F-31-10:/home/try$ php i.php
It's big, it's heavy, it's wood!

root@domU-12-31-39-0F-31-10:/home/try$ php i.php >loh.txt &
[1] 8928
root@domU-12-31-39-0F-31-10:/home/try$
[1]+  Done                    php i.php > loh.txt
root@domU-12-31-39-0F-31-10:/home/try$
root@domU-12-31-39-0F-31-10:/home/try$ cat loh.txt
It's big, it's heavy, it's wood!
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use **screen** ?? man screen

Answer (score 0):

can you try to do this, in the same directory where your log is ?

```
echo "test" > log.txt
```

It'll may disqualifie a file system full and read only file system options.